# Optimizing py2neo's cypher insertion

Tags: python, neo4j, graph-databases, py2neo

I am using py2neo to import several hundred thousand nodes. I've created a defaultdict to map neighborhoods to cities. One motivation was to more efficiently import these relationships having been unsuccessful with [Neo4j's load tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444845/how-can-i-efficiently-create-unique-relationships-in-neo4j).

Because the [batch documentation](http://py2neo.org/2.0/batch.html) suggests to avoid using it, I veered away from an implementation like the OP of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730308/inserting-large-graph-data-into-neo4j-using-py2neo-writebatch). Instead the documentation suggests I use Cypher. However, I like the being able to create nodes from the defaultdict I have created. Plus, I found it too difficult importing this information as the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444845/how-can-i-efficiently-create-unique-relationships-in-neo4j) demonstrates.

To reduce the speed of the import, should I create a [Cypher transaction](http://py2neo.org/2.0/intro.html#transactions) (and submit every 10,00) instead of the following loop?

```
for city_name, neighborhood_names in city_neighborhood_map.iteritems():
     city_node = graph.find_one(label="City", property_key="Name", property_value=city_name)
         for neighborhood_name in neighborhood_names:
              neighborhood_node = Node("Neighborhood", Name=neighborhood_name)
              rel = Relationship(neighborhood_node, "IN", city_node)
              graph.create(rel)
```

I get a time-out, and it appears to be pretty slow when I do the following. Even when I break up the transaction so it commits every 1,000 neighborhoods, it still processes very slowly.

```
tx = graph.cypher.begin()
statement = "MERGE (city {Name:{City_Name}}) CREATE (neighborhood { Name : {Neighborhood_Name}}) CREATE (neighborhood)-[:IN]->(city)"
for city_name, neighborhood_names in city_neighborhood_map.iteritems():
    for neighborhood_name in neighborhood_names:
        tx.append(statement, {"City_Name": city_name, "Neighborhood_Name": neighborhood_name})
tx.commit()
```

It would be fantastic to save pointers to each city so I don't need to look it up each time with the merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be faster to do this in two runs, i.e. `CREATE` all nodes first with unique constraints (which should be very fast) and then `CREATE` the relationships in a second round.

Constraints first, use Labels `City` and `Neighborhood`, faster `MATCH` later:

```
graph.schema.create_uniqueness_constraint('City', 'Name')
graph.schema.create_uniqueness_constraint('Neighborhood', 'Name')
```

Create all nodes:

```
tx = graph.cypher.begin()

statement = "CREATE (:City {Name: {name}})"
for city_name in city_neighborhood_map.keys():
    tx.append(statement, {"name": city_name})

statement = "CREATE (:Neighborhood {Name: {name}})"
for neighborhood_name in neighborhood_names: # get all neighborhood names for this
    tx.append(statement, {name: neighborhood_name})

tx.commit()
```

Relationships should be fast now (fast `MATCH` due to constraints/index):

```
tx = graph.cypher.begin()
statement = "MATCH (city:City {Name: {City_Name}}), MATCH (n:Neighborhood {Name: {Neighborhood_Name}}) CREATE (n)-[:IN]->(city)"
for city_name, neighborhood_names in city_neighborhood_map.iteritems():
    for neighborhood_name in neighborhood_names:
        tx.append(statement, {"City_Name": city_name, "Neighborhood_Name": neighborhood_name})

tx.commit()
```

Comment: As I mentioned in this link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30444845/how-can-i-efficiently-create-unique-relationships-in-neo4j), neighborhoods aren't unique, so I can't create a uniqueness constraint. Because of this, I can't create cities and neighborhoods separately, and need to merge on the relationship.

Comment: Why are they not unique? Just add them by name, if a neighborhood is in multiple cities, the city-neighborhood relationship contains that information.

Comment: Because a neighborhood named "Downtown" can appear in multiple cities. I think there should be a unique node to represent each neighborhood named "Downtown." Do you agree with this structure?

Comment: Depends on the queries. Why not just Downtown and a link between a city and Downtown?

Comment: Because there's unique information about each Downtown (like population size). I think it would be better to have a distinct node for each downtown.

Comment: create distinct nodes then.. creating nodes first and relationships later is still faster.

Comment: "Because there's unique information about each Downtown" : then you can put the information as property in the relationship.

Comment: Is it necessary to commit if I don't use transactions? When I newly create a database, everything works fine. But once I restart the neo4j community server, the results are wrong, even the number of relationships and nodes are wrong. What can be the issue?